# FormDataでバイナリをpostしたい

Tags: javascript, ajax

自動化のスクリプトを作っています。
目的のサイトでバイナリファイルを手作業でアップロードすると、Chromeのコンソールのnetworkから送られたFormDataを見るとfile: (binary)となっています。FormDataでbinaryと認識されるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Blobでは中身は取り出せないのでFaileReaderで中身を読んで、特定の型付き配列で送信する？と思い以下を試しましたがだめでした。file: [Object object]になってしまいます。

```
xhr.responseType = 'blob'
xhr.onload = () => {
  let fr = new FileReader()
  fr.onload = e=> {
    let ab = new ArrayBuffer(fr.response)
    new Uint8Array(ab)//post
  }
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(xhr.response)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

上記には

> Blob オブジェクトはファイルに似たオブジェクトで、immutable な**生データ**です。データを表す blob は必ずしも
>   JavaScript ネイティブなフォーマットではありません。

とあったのでblobオブジェクトのまま送ってみたりもしましたが、file: [Object object]になってしまい、バイナリの生データとして送信できません。ご存知でしたらご教示いただければ幸いです。

質問追記

送信時にnew Blob([data], {type: image/png})とすることで、開発ツール>Network>Headers>FormDataのView parsedの値はfile: [object Object]からfile: (binary)にすることができました。が、View sourceを見ると

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryuGkybuBnzAfvgUoP
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
>   Content-Type: image/png
>
> [object Object]

となっており、手作業でやった場合[object Object]がないという違いがあります。これはどういうことでしょうか？返ってきたエラーもjpg,pngのみとありるので、これが原因だと思います。ご教示いただければ幸いです。

上記の結果が得られたコードは以下です。

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.responseType = 'blob'
xhr.onload = () => {
    let fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('file', new Blob([xhr.response], {type : 'image/png'}))
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : url
        data : fd,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false
    })
    .done(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .fail((a,b,c) => {
        console.log(a,b,c)
    })
                }
xhr.open('GET', imgs[i], true)
xhr.send()
```

Comment: この辺でしょうか。[どうすればjavascriptはblobをアップロードできますか？](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20181227/78580.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。file: [object Object]で変わりありませんでした。

Comment: @kunif リンク先は stackoverflow のコンテンツを(無断で)機械翻訳したサイトです。参照先として示すにはあまり適さない気がします。

Comment: @cibick 検索上位に来ることが多いので困りものですが、気を付けます。ではこちらで、作成時にタイプ指定でしょうか。[File APIs(Blob, BlobURL, ArrayBuffer, FileReader)](https://qiita.com/TypoScript/items/0d5b08cecf959b8b822c#blob)

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: @bafcom 是非、どのように解決できたのか自己回答をしてください！

Comment: @kunif （質問とは関係ないですが） https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2905/2376 でSOの機械翻訳サイト等から元質問へ自動的にリダイレクトできるスクリプト等も紹介されています。参考にどうぞ

Comment: @hinaloe おお、ありがとうございます。助かります。

Comment: すいません。勘違いしており、まだ解決できていないかもしれません。質問欄に追記いたしますので、よろしければご教示をお願いします。

Comment: FileReaderとかを使ったりしているからかもしれません。最初からBlobで作成してみては？ [JavaScriptによるファイルとバイナリデータの扱い](http://amaraimusi.sakura.ne.jp/note_prg/JavaScript/file_binary.html), [Blob オブジェクトを作成する](http://hakuhin.jp/js/file.html#FILE_01) それから細切れのソースや結果情報ではなく、もう少しまとまった範囲の機能や処理のかたまりを記述した方が、筋の通ったアドバイスや回答を得られやすいでしょう。

Comment: ご指摘の通り編集しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問に追記されたコードをためしてみましたが、おそらく正しく動作しているようにみえます。参考になるかはわかりませんが、jQueryとブラウザのバージョンもおしえてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。バージョン: 77.0.3865.120（Official Build） （64 ビット）jquery 3.4.1です。